# Equivalent IPython code in .12 series

Tags: ipython

Using IPython .10-2, I can do the following from a python command line program:

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
IPShellEmbed(argv=[])()
```

This spawns an interactive IPython session at the point of invocation. I have been unable to find an equivalent for the .12 series of IPython.

Is there?

thanks, jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

There's lots more info in [the docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython).